# Sort numbers with 0 as the last priority, PL/SQL keyword for priority

Tags: asp.net, oracle, sorting, plsql

I have:

```
PROCEDURE A
(
    inId    IN NUMBER,
    RC1           OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
tMessage VARCHAR2(128);

BEGIN
    OPEN RC1 FOR
           SELECT * FROM 
           (  
                  SELECT 
                         a.company,
                  SUM(a.holding_balance) balance
                  FROM  TableNameEntries A

                   WHERE
                        A.BATCH_ID = inId 
                   GROUP BY a.company        
           )
                   ORDER BY balance DESC  ; 

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
             tMessage :='Exception ' || SQLCODE || ': ' || SQLERRM;            
    OPEN RC1 FOR
    SELECT tMessage FROM DUAL;

END A;
```

For the balance column, I have values like -1, 0,1. Currently it's sorted like 1 0 -1, but I don't care about the zeros, so I want it to be like -1,1,0 or 1,-1,0

How do I do it in PL/SQL? I tried:

```
 SELECT 
                         a.company,
                  SUM(a.holding_balance) balance
                  FROM  REC.CAG_GL_ENTRIES A

                   WHERE
                        A.BATCH_ID = 201311 
                   order by case priority when 0 then 2 else 1 END   priority
```

But it's saying PRIORITY is invalid identifier.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ORDER BY CASE balance 
            WHEN 0 THEN null
            ELSE balance
         END 
      DESC NULLS LAST
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways in your case (second is more common, first is more clear):

```
SELECT a.company,
       SUM(a.holding_balance) balance
FROM  REC.CAG_GL_ENTRIES A
WHERE A.BATCH_ID = 201311 
order by abs(balance) desc;

SELECT a.company,
       SUM(a.holding_balance) balance
FROM  REC.CAG_GL_ENTRIES A
WHERE A.BATCH_ID = 201311 
order by decode(balance,1,1,-1,1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY SIGN(ABS(balance)) DESC, balance
```

ABS() turns all the negatives to positives. SIGN() turns 0 to 0, >0 to 1 (and <0 to -1). Combined with DESC this puts all the zeros at the end and all the non-zeros above them in no particular order.
Then I sorted by the balance again to order the non-zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

`order by balance * balance desc`